# Integrate Redux in Polymer / Typescript project

Tags: typescript, polymer, redux, polymer-1.0

I try on the basis of [polymer-typescript-starter-kit](https://github.com/tony19/polymer-typescript-starter-kit) to integrate [polymer-redux](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux). I created a branch to try that here [polymer-redux-typescript-example](https://github.com/pme123/polymer-redux-typescript-example/tree/with-starter-kit).

Goals are:

1. Testing the ReduxStore `yarn tezt` [1](https://github.com/tony19/polymer-typescript-starter-kit)
2. Testing the web-components `yarn test` [1](https://github.com/tony19/polymer-typescript-starter-kit)
3. Use the ReduxStore in a Polymer element. [3](https://github.com/pme123/polymer-redux-typescript-example/tree/with-starter-kit)

1 and 2 work with my solution.

3 I get an exception on UI (Failed to load resource: http://localhost:8080/redux.js the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found))

If I add redux.js manually I got another exception.

Here is my redux-store.ts:

```
import {createStore} from "redux";
import {ReduxState, Customer, ReduxAction, ActionType} from "./entities";
// no typings for polymer-redux
import * as PolymerRedux from "../../bower_components/polymer-redux/polymer-redux.js";

export default class ReduxStore {

  static ReduxBehavior: any;

  initialState: ReduxState = {customer: {age: 30, name: 'Polymer Redux'}};

  constructor() {
    const store = createStore(this.appReducer);
    ReduxStore.ReduxBehavior = PolymerRedux(store);
  }

  appReducer = (state: ReduxState, action: ReduxAction) => {
    ...
  }

 ...
}
```

Here my my-custom-elem.ts

```
import {Customer, ReduxAction, ActionType} from "../../scripts/entities";
import ReduxStore from "../../scripts/redux-store";

@component('my-customer-elem')
@behavior(ReduxStore.ReduxBehavior)
class CustomerElem extends polymer.Base {

  // statePath is an extension of Polymer.property - throws transpile exception
  @property({type: Object, statePath: 'customer'} as any)
  customer: Customer;

  ...
}

CustomerElem.register();
```

Here is my-customer-elem.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-customer-elem">
  <template>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>System.import('components/my-customer-elem/my-customer-elem');</script>
```